# Python [Pydantic] - default values based other object in the class

Tags: python, pydantic

I would like to set default email in case email not provided,
i.e:

```
name = a 
last_name = b
email = None
```

email will become "a_b@email.com"

I tried something like that but obviously didn't work as the name,last_name
not define in function.

```
class User(BaseModel):
     name: Optional[str] = ''
     last_name: Optional[str] = ''
     email: EmailStr
    

    @validator('email')
    def set_email(cls, email):
        if not email:
           return name + last_name + '@email.com' 
        else:
           return email
```

Update- still not working,
i tried:

```
    @root_validator(pre=True)
    def email_set_config(cls, values):
        email, name ,last_name = values.get('email'), values.get('name') , values.get('last_name')
        if email is None :
            email= name + '_' + name + '@' + last_name 
        return values
```

Solution:

added to Class :

--Update

- Actually it is working without define class Config:

```
    class Config:
        validate_assignment = True
```

```
    @validator('email')
    def set_email(cls, v, values, **kwargs):
        return email or values["name"] + '_' + values["name"] + '@' + ["last_name"]
```

Comment: Try to use @root_validator

Comment: @NobbyNobbs - thanks for suggestion , not working , post updated .

Comment: actually it works, you don't update values dictionary in your implementation, but set local variable instead. Just fix it :)

Comment: @NobbyNobbs - figured out , 
i update the solution in post , can u explain when root_validator is require?

Answer (score 5):

Not enough reputation to comment, so I'll just expand on @NobbyNobbs answer here^^

For your last example using `pydantic.validator`, you can use the `always` kwargs to always run a validator even if the value is not provided.

Link in the doc: https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/validators/#validate-always

So your example would be:

```py
from typing import Optional

import pydantic


class User(pydantic.BaseModel):
    first_name: str
    last_name: str
    email: Optional[pydantic.EmailStr]

    @pydantic.validator('email', always=True)
    def set_email(cls, v, values, **kwargs):    
        return v or values["first_name"] + '_' + values["last_name"] + '@email.com'


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(User(first_name="jon", last_name="doe"))  # first_name='jon' last_name='doe' email='jon_doe@email.com'
    print(User(first_name="jon", last_name="doe", email=None))  # first_name='jon' last_name='doe' email='jon_doe@email.com'
```

Answer (score 3):

I changed your model a bit, now it has two required fields and one optional, which calculated from the others two.

```py
from typing import Optional

import pydantic


class User(pydantic.BaseModel):
    first_name: str
    last_name: str
    email: Optional[pydantic.EmailStr]
```

First approach to validate your data during instance creation, and have full model context at the same time, is using the `@pydantic.root_validator`:

```py
    @pydantic.root_validator
    def email_set_config(cls, values):
        email, name, last_name = values.get('email'), values.get('first_name'), values.get('last_name')
        if email is None:
            values["email"] = name + '_' + last_name + '@email.com'
        return values


if __name__ == "__main__":
    u = User(first_name="jon", last_name="doe")
    print(u)  # first_name='jon' last_name='doe' email='jon_doe@email.com'
```

But if you want to control instantiation process only, I suggest you just override `__init__` dunder in your model like this

```py
    def __init__(__pydantic_self__, **data: Any) -> None:
        email, name, last_name = data.get('email'), data.get('first_name'), data.get('last_name')
        if email is None:
            data["email"] = name + '_' + last_name + '@email.com'
        super().__init__(**data)
```

It's more simple and intuitive approach comparing to validator on my sight, and I would prefer it.

The possible solution with non-root validator, you mention in question, has tricky and a bit unexpected behavior for me.

It works like expected if you pass named `email` argument to constructor, but doesn't if you not.

```
    @pydantic.validator('email')
    def set_email(cls, v, values, **kwargs):
        return v or values["first_name"] + '_' + values["last_name"] + '@email.com'


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(User(first_name="jon", last_name="doe"))  # first_name='jon' last_name='doe' email=None
    print(User(first_name="jon", last_name="doe", email=None))  # first_name='jon' last_name='doe' email='jon_doe@email.com'
```

Comment: NobbyNobbs,
thanks much for your great ,detailed explanation! learnt something useful:)

Answer (score 0):

In my case the solution was:

```
@pydantic.root_validator(pre=True)
def method_before_validation(cls, data):
```

I used It in the root class of a complex object.
I have smth like object with orders and separate object with client and I needed to put client's id to each order's object.
So we can make data modification with data structure, types e.t.c on fly before the actual validation.

Answer (score -4):

Pydantic has added `default_factory` since v1.5, you can use the below code to have the default EmailStr value, as well as the other submodel class object

```py
class User(BaseModel):
     name: Optional[str] = ''
     last_name: Optional[str] = ''
     email: EmailStr = Field(
         default_factory=lambda: EmailStr('foo@example.org'))
```